# Magento payment gateway documentation

Tags: javascript, php, xml, magento

By official documentation main predefined functions for payment gateways are `capture()` and `authorize()` which should've been executed after the order is placed with selected payment method.

Payment gateway I'm trying to setup is **requesting https POST data and return json response**. It's basically only cc payment gateway.

1. *Where should this post data be rightfully placed inside module?*
2. *How to use gateways json response after completing of the order for display (so I know it executed correctly)?*
3. *How should module structure look like to meet most basic needs of this task?*

**This is what my code is trying to do:**

```
<?php

    class Mycompany_Pay_Model_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
    {
        protected $_code = 'mycompany_pay';

        protected $_isGateway               = true;
        protected $_canCapture              = true;
        protected $_canRefund               = true;
        protected $_canUseInternal          = true;

        protected $_allowCurrencyCode = array('EUR', 'HRK');

        protected $_minValue = 1;

        // taking predefined objects for further usage
        public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount){
            $order = $payment->getOrder();
            //$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            $billingInfo = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

            $postfields = array('order_id'=>9999, // temp number for debugging 
                    'name'=>    $customer->getName(), 
                    'mail'=>    $customer->getEmail(), 
                    'address'=> $billingInfo->getStreet(1),
                    'zip'=>     $billingInfo->getPostcode(),
                    'city'=>    $billingInfo->getCity(),
                    'state'=>   $billingInfo->getRegion(),
                    'country'=> $billingInfo->getCountry(),
                    'amount'=>  $amount,
                    'currency'=>$order->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
                    'cc'=>      $payment->getCcNumber(),
                    'cvv'=>     $payment->getCcCid());

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mygatewayUrl');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        print $result;
        }
    }
```

Should curl code be executed outside of capture? Whenever I do test order from my magento test site I just get returned with transaction ID saying order is complete. There is no actual proof that this capture even runs. (I tried adding log/breakpoints to it, done nothing at all).

**One additional question:**

*What is the easiest way of adding simple CC form for user to fill upon selecting this payment method (so CC variables are actually not empty like they are now)?*

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you have multiple questions you should ask them on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I think the method to achieve what you want is explained in this tutorial:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based

I could extract parts of it to answer your question but I think the whole overview that Manish Prakash gives would get lost, it covers the whole process in a very clear way, take a look.